# Как определить, что объект на холсте скрыт

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Решил сделать игру на Tkinter, у меня есть её почти готовый вид, не буду углубляться в саму игру.

Есть противник, он - это канвас фото. (PhotoImage, canvas.create_image) сначала он должен быть скрыт, как это реализовать правильно? Позже, мне надо будет проверить с помощью IF скрыт ли он, в этом сама проблема.

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
canvas.itemconfig(self, state='hidden')
```

Он справился с сокрытием врага, но как теперь проверить скрыт ли он? Есть функция, она постоянно должна проверять скрыт ли противник. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если метод `itemconfig` вызвать без дополнительных параметров (передать только `id` нужного объекта на холсте), то он вернет значения всех параметров объекта в виде словаря (см. [`Canvas.itemconfig`](https://tkinter-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/canvas.html#Canvas.itemconfig)).

Соответственно, чтобы получить `state`, нужно из этого словаря получить данные по ключу `"state"`:

```
canvas.itemconfig(item_id, state="hidden")
print(canvas.itemconfig(item_id)["state"])  # ('state', '', '', '', 'hidden')
print("hidden" in canvas.itemconfig(item_id)["state"])  # True
```

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую. Суть уловил

Comment: Можете пояснить, что такое ( hidden in canvas... ) Он выводит скрыт ли обьект? Или что он делает

Comment: @bfgquaka если буквально, то проверяет, что в `canvas.itemconfig(item_id)["state"]` есть элемент `"hidden"`. По смыслу - да, проверяет что объект скрыт.

Comment: спасибо, я смог применить